# Get category collection with like query in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I want to show all category list in an auto-suggest field. So I have a code with like query as:

```
function res($cur_category){
        $children_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($cur_category->getId());
    $children_categories->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%a%'));  
        foreach($children_categories as $child){
             $name = $child->getName();
        $option.='<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($child->getName()).'\');">' .$child->getName(). "</li>";
        $option.=res($child);
        }
    unset($children_categories);
        return $option;
}

function GetTree(){
    $rootcatId= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootcatId);
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%a%')); 
    foreach($categories as $category) 
    {   
        $option.='<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($category->getName()).'\');">'.$category->getName()."</li>";
        if($category->hasChildren()){
        $option.= res($category);
        }
    }
    unset($categories);
    return $option;
} 
echo $select = '<ul>'.GetTree().'</ul>';
```

But this code is not working with like query, without like query it is working fine and show category list properly. How can I write the query with like?

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to the use of the "addAttributeToFilter" method, or using the "getCategories" to define the collection... My best suggestion is to change up the way you're pulling the collections. I haven't tested this in a function, it's always been a direct .phtml file, but I always use the following structure to pull a collection (modified to fit your variables):

```
$children_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $cur_category->getId()))
                ->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => '%a%'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('include_in_menu',array('eq' => '1'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq' => '1'))
                ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
```

The last three methods are optional in your case, but I'll provide them here for those who want to retain only visible categories to be used in a menu, and sorted the same as your category tree.

And for the GetTree() method:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $rootcatId))
                ->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => '%a%'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('include_in_menu',array('eq' => '1'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq' => '1'))
                ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
```

Let me know if this helps, or you're still running into an issue.